# I've made an unbeatable Tic Tac Toe AI, but I'd want to make it "dumber"

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe

I've made a Tic Tac Toe AI using the following rules: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)

> Win: If the player has two in a row, they can place a third to get three in a row.
>
> Block: If the opponent has two in a row, the player must play the third themselves to block the opponent.
>
> Fork: Create an opportunity where the player has two threats to win (two non-blocked lines of 2).
>   Blocking an opponent's fork:
>
> - Option 1: The player should create two in a row to force the opponent into defending, as long as it doesn't result in them creating a fork. For example, if "X" has a corner, "O" has the center, and "X" has the opposite corner as well, "O" must not play a corner in order to win. (Playing a corner in this scenario creates a fork for "X" to win.)
> - Option 2: If there is a configuration where the opponent can fork, the player should block that fork.
>
> Center: A player marks the center. (If it is the first move of the game, playing on a corner gives "O" more opportunities to make a mistake and may therefore be the better choice; however, it makes no difference between perfect players.)
>
> Opposite corner: If the opponent is in the corner, the player plays the opposite corner.
>
> Empty corner: The player plays in a corner square.
>
> Empty side: The player plays in a middle square on any of the 4 sides.

So now, I'd want to implement some kind of system, to change it's difficulty dynamically.

Comment: add in a random number generator. When selecting a move, use the RNG  to determine whether instead of choosing the optimal move, it will choose a random move.

Comment: I think what you are referring to here is artificial unintelligence :-)

Comment: Artificial ignorance?

Comment: What i think is the range of random numbers > less range > more accurate more difficult... higher range > less accurate > less difficult

Comment: You have 6 rules listed here pretty in order of importance for playing well. You could make level 1 only know the first rule and play randomly if that doesn't apply, level 2 could know the first two rules and play randomly if none of those apply, and so on.

Comment: I played Tic Tac Toe with a chicken at a fair once that also couldn't be beat.

Comment: @juharr - I am not sure if that says more about the chicken or about you!!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Well I was like 7 at the time so....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could apply some subset of the above rules based on difficulty, for example:

Easy - Block, Empty Corner, Empty Side, Win

Medium - Block, Center, Empty Corner, Empty Side, Win

Hard - Block, Center, Empty Corner, Empty Side, Opposite Corner, Win

Insane - Block, Fork, Center, Empty Corner, Empty Side, Opposite Corner, Win

This wouldn't be too hard to implement, just add an enumeration of types bound to a difficulty radio button that deactivates on start. Then check difficulty in each of these checks:

```
If(some stuff && difficulty.In("HARD", "INSANE")) 
    OppositeCorner();
```

Answer (score 1):

To build a non perfect AI you could order all possible moves by how good they are and then not always choose the best.

The best should always be the one given by your list of rules, but you would have to define values of all other combinations (i.e. playing the corner if there is a possibility to place the third in a row, which is not that corner, etc.).